# masking a certain region of the image with black pixels

Tags: python, r, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I have hundreds of images where the bottom part of the image contains a slanted white/gray line. I need to do some blob detection and tracking of the blob above that line.

I need to replace all pixels on and below the slanted line in all image frames. The position of the line is same in all images. 
is there a Matlab or python or R way to do it.

Here are two sample images. You can see the bottom portion has a slanted line. I need to replace that with black pixels and all the region below that with black pixels.

[image][image]

Comment: You can do this in any of those languages. It would be nice if you could pick one. Also, since SO is not a code writing service, it would be nice if you had an actual question about your code that we could answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question contains both `opencv` and `python` tags, hence you can use the `cv2.fillPoly()` function available in OpenCV. You will have to pass all the pixel locations (in an array) of the image which need to be replaced by black pixels.

The following is a small illustration:

Consider the following image of shape 5x5 :

```
array([[255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255]])
```

Now I have an array of pixel locations which need to be replaced by black pixels in `pts`:

```
array([[0, 4], [1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 3], [4, 3], 
       [0, 5], [1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 4], [4, 4], 
       [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 5]])
```

Using `cv2.fillPoly`:

```
cv2.fillPoly(a, pts1, 0)
```

This returns:

```
array([[255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0]])
```

You can extend the same approach to your image provided you have all the necessary pixels locations.